# How can I deserialize an enum when the case doesn't match?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{ "type": "suite", "event": "started", "test_count": 1 }
```

I want to deserialize into these structs:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum ResultType {
    Suite,
    Test,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum ResultEvent {
    Started,
    Failed,
    Ok,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct JsonResult {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "type"))]
    test_type: ResultType,
    event: ResultEvent,
    test_count: Option<u32>,
}
```

I can't find a way to make serde_json use the correct case. I keep getting these errors:

```
Error("unknown variant `suite`, expected `Suite` or `Test`", line: 1, column: 17)
```

If I change the case of the enum values to all lowercase or all uppercase it works, but I'd like to be able to use PascalCase.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You just need to put [`#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#rename_all) before the enum definition.

Other possible values are `lowercase`, `UPPERCASE`, `PascalCase`, `camelCase`, `snake_case`, `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`, `kebab-case`, and `SCREAMING-KEBAB-CASE`.

Comment: I needed `lowercase` but this is indeed the fix! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to support different capitalisations, you can add an `alias` on the enum variants:

```rs
enum ResultType {
    #[serde(alias="suite", alias="SUITE")]
    Suite,
    #[serde(alias="test", alias="TEST")]
    Test,
}
```

In this case, either `"Suite"`, `"suite"` or `"SUITE"` is acceptable.

And any other case like `"sUitE"`, there must be something wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Use `#[serde(rename = "name")]` to change the string used for the enum variant when serializing and deserializing.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum ResultType {
    #[serde(rename = "suite")]
    Suite,
    #[serde(rename = "test")]
    Test,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum ResultEvent {
    #[serde(rename = "started")]
    Started,
    #[serde(rename = "failed")]
    Failed,
    #[serde(rename = "ok")]
    Ok,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct JsonResult {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "type"))]
    test_type: ResultType,
    event: ResultEvent,
    test_count: Option<u32>,
}
```

You can also use `#[serde(alias = "name")]` to add an extra string to accept when deserializing.

Details are in the serde documentation: https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html